# Access dbus session bus from upstart script

Tags: upstart, dbus

I was wandering if it is possible to access the DBUS session bus from within an upstart script.

The background is this:
I am running an upstart task in user mode and replaced the `Upstart.conf` dbus configuration file with the one from the **upstart bzr** repository.

Now it would like to access the gnome keyring within that tasks script using [gkeyring](https://launchpad.net/gkeyring), which needs to access the users upstart session bus. By default, I just get the `Gnome keyring not available`.

When I try to export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=...` within the upstart script, the `script/initctl` command just hangs, no output anywhere.

This leads me to believe that since upstart uses DBUS as well, using the session bus is problematic. Does someone have an idea to resolve this?

Comment: There could be multiple session buses for a user, so this isn't an easy one to answer.  Have you considered launching your app as part of the user session instead?

Comment: problem with that approach, is lack of robustness on failure, upstart restarts/logs as such.

Answer (score 2):

this might work for you ?...

```
script
    export HOME="/home/puma"
    chdir /home/puma/apps/whatever/bin
    dbus_file=$(ls $HOME/.dbus/session-bus/ -t1 | head -1)
    . "$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/$dbus_file"
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS;exec /home/puma/apps/whatever/bin/appname' puma 
end script
```

hope it helps ?

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! Thank you very much, i tried all the methods http://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users and this is what worked... bluez-mpris-player aka mpris-proxy requires access to the session bus that your mpris2 player (Audacious) is running on. Now I have working AVRCP 1.3 (track changed metadata) with Bluez 4.101  (org.bluez.MediaPlayer) on Precise 12.04.5 with my carputer, paired to A2DP Bluetooth in Toyota Corolla I hope those with google foo can find this!

Answer (score 0):

If for all the processes who wants to access session bus the same `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable is set, you are going to have no problems (see [the manual](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html)). **But** since upstart tasks are run in a "[restrictive environment](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-environment)" you will not have access to that variable in a system job (e.g. those under `/etc/init`). However if you were to have it as a session job (e.g. under `/usr/share/upstart/sessions`) you are going to have access to a lot of more environment variables. Moreover such jobs are not executed as `root` but as the session user. For example:

```
start on started dbus
stop on stopping dbus

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

kill timeout 20

exec /PATH/TO/MY/JOB
```